# return multiple pandas Dataframes as single Django zip files (one file per DF) HttpResponse

Tags: python, pandas, zip

I trying to figure out a way to return multiple dataframes from a Django view as Zip  HttpResponse(zip_file, content_type="application/x-zip-compressed")

I tried this:

```
import zipfile
import datetime
def makeZipfiles(df_list):
    i = 0
    with zipfile.ZipFile('some_zip.zip', 'w') as csv_zip:
        for dfl in df_list:
            csv_zip.writestr(f"file_{str(i)}.csv", dfl.to_csv(index=False))
            i = i + 1

    return csv_zip
```

and in the view, I have the following:

```
zip_file = makeZipfiles(df_list)
response = HttpResponse(zip_file, content_type="application/x-zip-compressed")
return response
```

but when I try to look at the zip file in the download folder, I get an error that the 'archive is either unknown format or damaged'.   The exported file is 1KB size and when I open in notepad I see this content only

"<zipfile.ZipFile [closed]>"

Please advise if what I am trying to do is feasible and if so, please provide a sample code.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this out myself yet, but it seems to fit your demand quite well.

https://georepublic.info/en/blog/2019/zip-files-in-django-admin-and-python/

The author describes in detail how to **get .csv files** from the different dataframes and **zip them** in the end to **one file** for download.

His final code was the following:

```
file_list = [
. . .,
UserInfoResource()
]

def getfiles():
    fileSet = {}
    date_now = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
    for file in file_list:
        dataset = file.export()
        dataset = dataset.csv
        name = file._meta.model.__name__ + date_now
        fileSet[name] = dataset

    return fileSet

def download_zip(request):
    files = getfiles()
    zip_filename = 'Survey_Data' + dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M') + '.zip'
zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, False) as zip_file:
        for k, file in files.items():
            zip_file.writestr(k + '.csv', file)
    zip_buffer.seek(0)
    resp = HttpResponse(zip_buffer, content_type='application/zip')
    resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename = %s' % zip_filename
    return resp
```

I will update this answer if I manage to apply this on my own website.
(Let us know if you found a better answer in the meantime, thanks ;) )